# Apply style to specific text in a styled paragraph using Docx4j

Tags: java, docx4j

How to apply *italic* style to a specific text in a styled paragraph using Docx4j?

Let's say a paragraph, as below, has been added to a document and it already has a style.

`word1 word2 word3 word4`

What I need is to apply *italic* style to **word3** and the general style of the paragraph is not modified, so words **word1** **word2** and **word4** keep as is.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you'll need word3 to be in a run (w:r) of its own, so you can apply run property (w:rPr) of italics (w:i) to it.

So first, you'll need logic to split the run, if necessary.

Then simply apply the formatting.  To see how to do that, create a docx (in Word say), with italics applied. The use the docx4j webapp or Word Helper AddIn to generate applicable code.

Comment: Could you please post some code on how to do it. I was able to generate the object using docx4j webapp but I didnt find it usefull. Not sure how to split runs also. Thx

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve it by unmarshalling a text string as below:

```
p = (P) XmlUtils.unmarshalString(
    "<w:p xmlns:w=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main\" xmlns:xml=\"http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace\">"
    + "<w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val=\"style\"/></w:pPr>"
    + "<w:r><w:t xml:space=\"preserve\">word1 word2 </w:t></w:r>"
    + "<w:r><w:rPr><w:i/></w:rPr><w:t>word3</w:t></w:r>"
    + "<w:r><w:t xml:space=\"preserve\"> word4</w:t></w:r></w:p>");
```

And adding it to the document.